# How do I examine the tail of a growing file on WSL-2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

On WSL `tail -f file` reports once and then does nothing even though the file is growing.

Is there a workaround short of writing my own?

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
tail  -f ---disable-inotify file
```

Note the 3 hyphens before "disable..."
This parameter makes tail to use polling to detect file changes and know when to read more data, which is inefficient but works anywhere.
By default tail uses inotify, even on filesystems without inotify support like Windows NTFS.

Some more information about this story at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/925

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why tail isn't properly updating but one workaround is that you can `less` the file then press `shift+g` to refresh it.

Comment: Good idea. Also I think shift+f will follow too like tail.

Comment: @sum1quiet The feature I was looking for in tail is to show data as it is added without having to repeatedly strike a character, so shift-G doesn't do it.

Comment: @Atmas -- less with the shift-F command does what I want and works acceptably on my 212 MB log files. Thanks.

Comment: Glad we could help. Upvoting thus answer even though it's a workaround since sum1 got the ball rolling.